# Why doesn't Rationalize work for 0. in Interval?

Tags: numerics, intervals

Same motivation as [this q](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89989/accuracy-of-real-valued-intervals?noredirect=1#comment246001_89989). Why doesn't `Rationalize` work for 0.?

```
Interval[{0., 1.}] // Map[Rationalize, #, {2}] &
```

> Interval[{-4.45015*10^-308,1}]

There's nothing wrong with 0. by itself:

```
{0., 1.} // Map[Rationalize]
```

> {0, 1}

Comment: You might want to adjust the second argument of `Rationalize[]` if seen fit.

Comment: `Map[Rationalize[#, 0] &, Interval[{0., 1.}], {2}]`

Comment: @belisarius, try this: `Interval[{0., 1.}] // 
 Map[Rationalize[#, 0.0000000000000001] &, #, {2}] &`

Comment: @Guesswhoitis., most positive values of 2nd parameters seem to work, though note above counterexample. But I want to know why this issue is `Interval` specific.

Comment: Interesting also is `Interval[{0., 1.}]/2 // Rationalize` for demonstrating how bad my floating-point intuition is.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Perhaps `Interval[{0., 1.}]/2 // Rationalize // Trace` and `$MinMachineNumber` shows that "though this be madness, yet there is method in't."

Comment: Again follows from standard evaluation semantics. If you want an exact zero, either use an exact zero or `Rationalize` before evaluating `Interval`.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this has to do with the fact that intervals "grow" just a bit on evaluation with machine numbers to ensure that values at the endpoint will be included in the interval.

```
NestList[Interval @@ # &, Interval[{0., 1.}], 5] // InputForm

(*
{Interval[{-2.2250738585072014*^-308, 1.0000000000000002}], 
 Interval[{-4.450147717014403*^-308, 1.0000000000000004}], 
 Interval[{-6.675221575521604*^-308, 1.0000000000000007}], 
 Interval[{-8.900295434028806*^-308, 1.0000000000000009}], 
 Interval[{-1.1125369292536007*^-307, 1.000000000000001}], 
 Interval[{-1.3350443151043208*^-307, 1.0000000000000013}]}
*)
```

I'm only guessing at why it is designed this way. The docs give a pretty vague description.

*"For approximate machine- or arbitrary-precision numbers x, Interval[x] yields an interval reflecting the uncertainty in x."*

**Edit:**

Just to make it a little more interesting, this is what it appears to be doing to the endpoints.

```
NestList[# + {$MinMachineNumber, $MachineEpsilon} &, {0., 1.}, 5] // InputForm

(*
{{0., 1.}, 
 {2.2250738585072014*^-308, 1.0000000000000002}, 
 {4.450147717014403*^-308, 1.0000000000000004}, 
 {6.675221575521604*^-308, 1.0000000000000007}, 
 {8.900295434028806*^-308, 1.0000000000000009}, 
 {1.1125369292536007*^-307, 1.000000000000001}}
*)
```

I suspect that in general the step is `$MachineEpsilon` but zero is a special case as it often is in Mathematica.

Comment: What's the transitive closure? This is a disaster waiting to happen in temporal queries or real time systems.

Comment: Yes, I have been bitten by this a time or two.