# NIntegrate appears to give incorrect results

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to specify a bivariate probability density function in Mathematica. As a check, I would like to confirm that it integrates to one. Here is the function:

```
f[x1_, x2_, u1_, u2_, v11_, v22_, v12_] := Det[2*Pi*{{v11, v12}, {v12, v22}}]^(-0.5)*(x1*x2*(1 - x1 - x2) )^(-1)*Exp[-0.5*(Log[{x1, x2}/(1 - x1 - x2)] - {u1, u2}).Inverse[{{v11, v12}, {v12, v22}}].(Log[{x1, x2}/(1 - x1 - x2)] - {u1, u2})]
```

Here, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the random variables, where $X_1 > 0$, $X_2 > 0$ and $X_1 + X_2 < 1$, and $U_1 \in \mathbb{R}$, $U_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, $V_{11}>0$, $V_{22}>0$ and $V_{12}\in \mathbb{R}$ are parameters.

Using `NIntegrate` to integrate over the $(X_1,X_2)$ space with non-zero density, with $U_1=U_2=V_{12}=0$ and $V_{11}=V_{22}=1$, I get:

```
NIntegrate[f[x1, x2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1 - x1}]
(* 0.364031 *)
```

The answer should be 1 (not 0.364 as above) for any choice of the parameters. I have specified the same function in the R language with only syntax changes. The function in R gives exactly the same values as in Mathematica when supplied with the same arguments (confirming that it is not a programming error). However, I get an integral of 1 in R using adaptive quadrature (i.e. a different answer to Mathematica!).

Any suggestions?

Miguel

Comment: If all you want is to specify a PDF, consider `ProbabilityDistribution[]` and its `Method -> "Normalize"` setting.

Comment: @J.M. That's not what I'm interested in. I want to know why NIntegrate is giving me an answer that is incorrect, both in theory and when checked against another package.

Comment: This seems to be a failure of the default integration method, then. Try adding `Method -> "UnitCubeRescaling"`. Also, it is advisable to use `1/2` instead of `0.5` in your PDF.

Comment: Hiding the symbolic form using `_?NumericQ` causes it to return 1.

Comment: @Miguel You could report this problem to Wolfram Support.

Comment: @J.M. Wouldn't `MultidimensionalRule` provide a more flexible solution? (both work)

Comment: @Feyre, it could, but that's a "rule" and not a "strategy"; that is, you're not actually doing adaptive cubature when using a rule, so it is possible to miss features in the integrand. But you can certainly use an integration rule if you know what you're doing, as that evaluates much faster.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! It seems to be a problem with the symbolic pre-processing that is fixed with either `_?NumericQ` or `Method -> "UnitCubeRescaling"`.

Comment: What I couldn't figure out though is how to explicitly turn off symbolic preprocessing, e.g. `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}` causes it to fail in other ways.

Comment: @Szabolcs, apparently the default method evaluates at the corners of the triangle when `"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0`; `Method -> {"DoubleExponential", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}` works.

Comment: `NIntegrate` seems to be using `"LevinRule"` but I don't know why.  And I don't know why it fails so badly.  Pretty much all the suggestions that work are just one way or another to prevent `"LevinRule"` from being applied.

Comment: Interesting: `N@ Integrate[f[x1, x2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1 - x1}]` yields ``0.5000000002523569` ``.  I also get `0.5` if I `Rationalize[]` the integrand and use `N[integral, prec]`.  `Integrate[]` factors out the `-1/(2 Pi)`, and for whatever reason, that changes the value returned by `NIntegrate[]` when `N` is applied.  Seems the integral is a pathological case for the Levin Rule (without the setting `MinRecursion` higher as Anton showed).

Comment: @Michael, David Levin designed his method specifically for oscillatories, so no surprise that it does poorly on something manifestly nonoscillatory. From your analysis, I guess the internal method-choosing code could do much better, since it has chosen poorly here.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, that is my thinking, too. I don't understand the internals of the Levin rule very well, nor why the rule fails by default but succeeds with `MinRecursion -> 1`. After all, it *can* work on nonoscillatory integrals, although, as you say, it's a poor choice and shouldn't be expected to work well. (To a certain extent I can see *what* it did wrong. Something tricks it into computing small integrals & errors on subregions.)

Answer (score 14):

The sampling points are insufficient in the first rule applications. Increasing them, say, with `MinRecursion` produces the expected result:

```
NIntegrate[f[x1, x2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1 - x1}, 
 MinRecursion -> 1]
(* 1. *)
```

An alternative is to use Cartesian rules:

```
NIntegrate[
 f[x1, x2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1 - x1}, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "ClenshawCurtisRule"}]
(* 1. *)
```

Changing the integration strategy to the simpler "Trapezoidal" or "MonteCarlo" also gives results close to 1.

Here are some sampling points plots for comparison:

```
Grid[Partition[
  Append[NIntegrateSamplingPoints[
      NIntegrate[
       f[x1, x2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1 - x1}, 
       Evaluate[Sequence @@ #]]], {PlotLabel -> #[[1]], 
      ImageSize -> 400}] & /@ {{Method -> Automatic}, {MinRecursion ->
       1}, {MinRecursion -> 
      2}, {Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", 
       Method -> "ClenshawCurtisRule"}}, {Method -> "Trapezoidal", 
     MaxRecursion -> 20}, {Method -> "MonteCarlo"}}, 3], 
 Dividers -> All, Alignment -> {Right, Left}]
```

[image]

Compare the plots above with the following plots of the integrand:

```
Grid[{{Plot3D[f[x1, x2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 4(*,Mesh\[Rule]All*), ImageSize -> 350], 
   DensityPlot[f[x1, x2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 4, Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 350]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to visually demonstrate that "(t)he sampling points are insufficient" within the triangle (hint, hint). ;)

Comment: @J.M. I acted upon your suggestion...

Comment: Thanks for indulging me. :) The undersampling is quite starkly shown in the upper leftmost picture.

Comment: @J.M. No problem, I thought it was a good idea to provide such plots, but decided to postpone making/posting them for later...

Comment: Any idea why the `Automatic` method chooses `"LevinRule"`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good question. I don't know. "LevinRule" was implemented/introduced after I left WRI, so I am not familiar with what logic it is plugged-in into `NIntegrate`.

Comment: @Michael, that's very weird; as you know, that thing is intended for oscillatory integrands. Clearly we have run into a bug.

Answer (score 7):

Aside from getting around the apparent weakness in the [`"LevinRule"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#32844337)* as others have suggested, here is another way to verify the total probability is `1`, namely, by changing variables.

```
{transformation} = 
 Solve[{u1, u2} == {Log[x1/(1 - x1 - x2)], Log[x2/(1 - x1 - x2)]}, {x1, x2}, Reals]
(*
  {{x1 -> E^u1/(1 + E^u1 + E^u2), 
    x2 -> -E^-u1 (-E^u1 + E^u1/(1 + E^u1 + E^u2) + E^(2 u1)/(1 + E^u1 + E^u2))}}
*)

jacobian = Det@D[{x1, x2} /. transformation, {{u1, u2}}] // Simplify
(*  E^(u1 + u2)/(1 + E^u1 + E^u2)^3  *)

(* new limits of integration *)
Reduce[{u1, u2} == {Log[x1/(1 - x1 - x2)], Log[x2/(1 - x1 - x2)]} &&
  0 < x1 < 1 && 0 < x2 < 1 - x1, {u1, u2}, {x1, x2}]
(*  (u1 | u2) ∈ Reals  *)

Integrate[
 f[x1, x2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0] * jacobian /. transformation,
 {u1, -∞, ∞}, {u2, -∞, ∞}]    (* implied by (u1 | u2) ∈ Reals *)
(*  1  *)
```

---

*The use of `"LevinRule"` and `"MultidimensionalRule"` in the OP's integral as the automatically chosen method can be seen by using the approach presented in [Determining which rule NIntegrate selects automatically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26401/determining-which-rule-nintegrate-selects-automatically/96663#96663), or by inspecting `calls` to the integration rules collected via

```
{calls} = Last@Reap@NIntegrate[f[x1, x2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1 - x1},
 IntegrationMonitor :> (Sow[#1] &)]
```

The output may be viewed in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhPf2.png).  I hesitate to call it a bug, if it were an edge-case that is hard to detect; numerical routines often have limitations.  There are two issues, why choose `"LevinRule"`, and why `"LevinRule"` gives wrong approximations `0.36` or `0.5` (if `1/(2 Pi)` is factored out of the integral sign as noted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120118/nintegrate-appears-to-give-incorrect-results/120122?noredirect=1#comment325470_120118)).

*Further remarks on the choice of `"LevinRule"` and a strange workaround.*
`NIntegrate` seems to conclude the integral is oscillatory, because of the following. The domain of integration is mapped to a unit square, which transforms the integrand to

```
Exp[1/2 * 
  (-Log[x1/(1 - x1 - (1 - x1) x2)]^2 - Log[((1 - x1) x2)/(1 - x1 - (1 - x1) x2)]^2) /
    (2 π x1 x2 (1 - x1 - (1 - x1) x2))
 ]
```

Whether the integrand is oscillatory is determined by whether the argument to `Exp` is real.  That depends on whether the arguments to the logarithms

```
x1/(1 - x1 - (1 - x1) x2), ((1 - x1) x2)/(1 - x1 - (1 - x1) x2)
```

are negative over the domain `0 <= x1 <= 1`, `0 <= x2 <= 1`.  This is determined by plugging the intervals in the form `Interval[{0, 1.}]` for `x1`, `x2` each.  But `Interval[]` is only guaranteed to compute an interval that ***contains*** the exact result.  But note that the computed intervals contain negative numbers:

```
{x1/(1 - x1 - (1 - x1) x2), ((1 - x1) x2)/(1 - x1 - (1 - x1) x2)} /. 
 Thread[{x1, x2} -> Interval[{0, 1.}]]
(*  {Interval[{-∞, ∞}], Interval[{-∞, ∞}]}  *)
```

However, the arguments are nonnegative:

```
Minimize[{#, 0 <= x1 <= 1 && 0 <= x2 <= 1}, {x1, x2}] & /@
 {x1/(1 - x1 - (1 - x1) x2), ((1 - x1) x2)/(1 - x1 - (1 - x1) x2)}
(*  {{0, {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 1/2}}, {0, {x2 -> 0, x1 -> 0}}}  *)
```

Before we conclude it is a bug, consider what's going on in the denominator of the arguments:

```
{1 - x1 - (1 - x1) x2, 1 - x1 - (1 - x1) x2 // Factor} /. 
 Thread[{x1, x2} -> Interval[{0, 1}]]
(*  {Interval[{-1, 1}], Interval[{0, 1}]}  *)
```

The first evaluates to `1 + Interval[{-1, 0}] + Interval[{-1, 0}]`, which is exactly right.  But the two intervals are treated as independent quantities, which originally they aren't, and so the interval sum comes out to be `Interval[{-1, 1}]`.  The factored expression yields a more precise result.

It gets more complicated when we consider approximate reals, such as `1.`.  `Interval` adds or subtracts an epsilon from the end points when calculating with them, so that `1 - Interval[{0, 1.}]` equals `Interval[{-4.44089*10^-16, 1}]`.  This has been discussed a little [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/90000/4999) and remarked on [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109597/a-weird-issue-with-intervalmaxnumber#comment297220_109597).

I'll leave off the analysis here, except to note that it suggested the following as a potential fix:

```
f2 = 1/Expand[1/f[x1, x2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]];

f2 == f[x1, x2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0] // Simplify  (* check algebraic equivalence *)
(*  True  *)

NIntegrate[f2, {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1 - x1}]
(*  1.  *)
```

Comment: Note that the OP's `f[x1, x2, y1, y2, v11,v22,v12]` is equivalent to the `PDF[]` of `xfdist = TransformedDistribution[{x1, x2} /. transformation, {u1, u2} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[{y1, y2}, {{v11, v12}, {v12, v22}}]]`

Comment: Very good analysis!