# Implementing Gauss–Laguerre quadrature for double integral of oscillatory function

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, warning-messages

I need an efficient way to evaluate a certain double integral for a wide range of parameters:

$$I=(\gamma_l \gamma_L )^{3/2}   \int_0^\infty \int_0^{1} \frac{r ~d r ~dx}{\sqrt{r^2+b^2 x^2}} \times  \\ \times L_l \left( 2 \gamma_l r \right) L_L \left(2 \gamma_L r \right) e^{-(\gamma_l+\gamma_L) r} \left((-1)^{(j-J)/2} \cos \beta^{-}_{jJ} x-(-1)^{(j+J)/2} \cos \beta^{+}_{jJ} x\right)$$

Where $j,J,l,L$ are integers, such that $j \pm J$ is even, and: $$\beta^{\pm}_{jJ}=\frac{\pi (j \pm J)}{2} \\ \gamma_l=\frac{1}{l+1/2}$$

while $b>1$ is just a real parameter. I may need to have $j,J$ as large as $100$ at least. $l,L$ can be under $20$.

A special case $j=J$ allows one to take half of the integral over $x$ exactly, however the second part still needs to be evaluated numerically.

I have tried to make a change of variables and evaluate function of the form:

$$F(\beta,s)=s \int_0^1 \frac{\cos \beta u~du}{\sqrt{s^2+u^2}}$$

However, that wasn't successful, so I decided to use [Gauss-Laguerre quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Laguerre_quadrature) for the integral over $r$, because it seems to fit well. I have obtained the formula:

$$I \approx \frac{(\gamma_l \gamma_L )^{3/2}}{(\gamma_l+\gamma_L)(N+1)^2} \sum_{n=1}^N  \frac{L_l \left( \frac{2 \gamma_l}{\gamma_l+\gamma_L} r_n \right) L_L \left(\frac{2 \gamma_L}{\gamma_l+\gamma_L} r_n \right)~r_n}{L_{N+1}^2(r_n)} 
 \times \\ \times \int_0^{1} \frac{(-1)^{(j-J)/2} \cos \beta^{-}_{jJ} x-(-1)^{(j+J)/2} \cos \beta^{+}_{jJ} x}{\sqrt{1+\frac{b^2}{(\gamma_l+\gamma_L)^2 r_n^2} x^2}} dx$$

This seems to work for small $j,J$, but both performance and accuracy suffer when compared to Mathematica double integration routine. For example (**updated after a comment about using** `PrecisionGoal`):

```
j = 11;
J = 23;
l = 2;
L = 5;
b = 10;
a1 = N[1/(l + 1/2), 20];
a2 = N[1/(L + 1/2), 20];
b1 = N[(\[Pi] j)/2, 20];
b2 = N[(\[Pi] J)/2, 20];
bm = b1 - b2;
bp = b1 + b2;
j1 = If[EvenQ[(j - J)/2], 1, -1];
j2 = If[EvenQ[J], 1, -1];
A0 = j1  N[(a1 a2)^(3/2), 20];
Nm = 10 Max[l, L, j, J];
A = (j1 (a1 a2)^(3/2))/((a1 + a2) (Nm + 1)^2);
S0 = (a1 + a2)^2 b^2;
S1 = b^2;
R = x /. NSolve[LaguerreL[Nm, x] == 0, 20];

T1 = AbsoluteTiming[R1 = (2 a1)/(a1 + a2) R;
  R2 = (2 a2)/(a1 + a2) R;
  w = (A R)/LaguerreL[Nm + 1, R]^2 LaguerreL[l, R1] LaguerreL[L, R2];
  S = S0/(R^2) ;
  If[EvenQ[j + J],   
   NIntegrate[
    Total[ w/Sqrt[1 + S u^2]] (Cos[bm u] - j2 Cos[bp u]), {u, 0, 1}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 5, Method -> "LevinRule"], 0]]
T2 = AbsoluteTiming[
  If[EvenQ[j + J], 
   A0 NIntegrate[(
     LaguerreL[l, 2 a1 r] LaguerreL[L, 
       2 a2 r] Exp[-r (a1 + a2)] r (Cos[bm u] - j2 Cos[bp u]))/Sqrt[
     r^2 + S1 u^2], {u, 0, 1}, {r, 0, Infinity}, PrecisionGoal -> 5], 
   0]]
```

I get:

```
{0.295737, 0.000107986}
{26.3857, 0.000107935}
```

For the double integral there's also extreme increase of error for GlobalAdaptive method (`NIntegrate::eincr`). Monte Carlo works better, but still takes very long.

---

As you can see, quadrature rule is more computationally stable and much faster*, but doesn't give very accurate results for a small number of nodes. Meanwhile, double integration suffers from both singularity and oscillations, which leads to loss of precision.

For larger $j,J$ double integration is extremely slow, and I'm not sure if it even gives results. However, quadrature is slow as well and only converges for large number of nodes.

> My questions are: is there a way to improve my implementation or find some other way of computing this integral for the specified range of parameters, with some degree of accuracy?
>
> Additionally, if I still use the quadrature rule, how do I choose the number of nodes correctly?
>
> In any case, for large $j,J$ double integral doesn't evaluate in several minutes and that's unacceptable. However, how do I check the accuracy of the approximate method without knowing the exact value?

I'm sorry for the length of the post, thank you for your time!

---

* that if we don't include the evaluation of the roots for the Laguerre polynomial. The roots of course can be pre-computed.

Comment: @AntonAntonov, thank you, it work better now. I need to read up on those

Comment: I have also tried to implement Levin algorithm explicitly, but I have precision loss issues with `LinearSolve`, and the runtime is not very good

Comment: It's a good idea to include the error messages (I got one) that your code generates. In this case the one I get suggests that one result is somewhat inaccurate.

Comment: @MichaelE2, you are right, I didn't include it, but I mentioned the error. I'll make sure to include next time

Comment: I see.  I thought you meant that the result was not consistent with a value known to you, not that `NIntegrate` has issued an error message. IMO, including the actual name `NIntegrate::eincr` potentially helps other users search for Q&As with similar problems.  Also, I originally mentioned it because occasionally you get different messages or no messages in different versions of *Mathematica*, and I want to check whether you were getting what I was getting.

Comment: Related discussion: ["NIntegrate appears to give incorrect results"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120118/34008).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems it is faster to use `Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}`:

```
T1 = AbsoluteTiming[R1 = (2 a1)/(a1 + a2) R;
  R2 = (2 a2)/(a1 + a2) R;
  w = (A R)/LaguerreL[Nm + 1, R]^2 LaguerreL[l, R1] LaguerreL[L, R2];
  S = S0/(R^2);
  If[EvenQ[j + J], 
   NIntegrate[
    Total[w/Sqrt[1 + S u^2]] (Cos[bm u] - j2 Cos[bp u]), {u, 0, 1}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
    Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", 
      "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}], 0]]

(* {0.221031, 0.000107986} *)


T2 = 
 AbsoluteTiming[
  If[EvenQ[j + J], 
   A0 NIntegrate[(LaguerreL[l, 2 a1 r] LaguerreL[L, 
         2 a2 r] Exp[-r (a1 + a2)] r (Cos[bm u] - j2 Cos[bp u]))/
      Sqrt[r^2 + S1 u^2], {u, 0, 1}, {r, 0, Infinity}, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
     Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", 
       "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}], 0]]

(* {1.05594, 0.000107929} *)
```

Are the results something you expect?

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to work very well for the double integral up to very high values of the parameters! I don't need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @YuriyS Great, good luck!

Answer (score 3):

This is a comment that extends Anton's answer.

Outside any small neighborhood of the origin, the integrand is analytic and you can take advantage of the spectral convergence of the Gauss and Gauss-Kronrod rules by increasing the number of Gauss points, especially along the u-axis.  Despite the r-integration being out to infinity, the convergence rate seems to be aided by the exponential decay of the integrand.  For the u-integration, convergence should begin around `"Points" -> 0.5 bp` or a little higher, and it reaches the desired goal a little under `bp` points.  The r-integration is a little harder to predict (for me).  A modestly high setting such as `"Points" -> 21` greatly speeds up the calculation, and the optimal setting for the given example is `"Points" -> 51`.

```
T1 = AbsoluteTiming[
  R1 = (2 a1)/(a1 + a2) R;
  R2 = (2 a2)/(a1 + a2) R;
  w = (A R)/LaguerreL[Nm + 1, R]^2 LaguerreL[l, R1] LaguerreL[L, R2];
  S = S0/(R^2);
  If[EvenQ[j + J],
   NIntegrate[
    Total[w/Sqrt[1 + S u^2]] (Cos[bm u] - j2 Cos[bp u]), {u, 0, 1}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
    Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> Ceiling[0.8 bp]}], 0]]
(*  {0.095939, 0.000107986}  *)

T2 = AbsoluteTiming[
  If[EvenQ[j + J], 
   A0 NIntegrate[
     (LaguerreL[l, 2 a1 r] LaguerreL[L, 2 a2 r] Exp[-r (a1 + a2)] r *
      (Cos[bm u] - j2 Cos[bp u]))/Sqrt[r^2 + S1 u^2],
     {u, 0, 1}, {r, 0, Infinity}, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 5, 
     Method -> {
       {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> Round[0.8 bp]}, 
       {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 51}}], 0]]
(*  {0.033414, 0.000107929}  *)
```

Another approach that is a little worse but still a significant improvement is to use the options:

```
Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 21},
MinRecursion -> Floor[Log2[bp/21]]
```

The number `21` can be replace by a lower or higher number.  Forcing preliminary recursive subdivision with `MinRecursion` speeds up the default setting `5` quite a bit as well.  `Ceiling` sometimes to yield a faster integration than `Floor` and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you. Turns out, I can change the variable to $s=r/b$ and then integrate only to $s \leq 1+\epsilon$, for example, $s \leq 5/4$, and the rest becomes a single integral with the square root approximated by its Taylor series. So I will also try your approach on the double integral with the limits $0\leq u \leq 1$ and $0 \leq s \leq 5/4$, see if it works faster

Comment: Turns out, your method performs better when the upper limit is $\infty$, but worse if the upper limit is $5/4$. In any case, your answer had been very helpful